# How to combine ListView and UpdateView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

In my web application, I have a template with ListView that shows list of table records, that works fine.
Now I want to allow user to update fields for each row of the table. 
One "easy" solution is to create an update page using UpdateView and put a link to it in each row. User can then click update, open update page ... But I am wondering if there is a way to update fields in the same table, without opening a new page.
Hope my question is clear.
thanks for your help

**UPDATE** (*and "my" solution*)

I managed to do it using formset:

**in forms.py**

```
class IssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Issue
        fields=('__all__')
IssueFormset=inlineformset_factory(IssuesList, Issue, form=IssueForm,extra=0)
```

**in views.py**

```
class IssuesListUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model=IssuesList
    fields='__all__'

    # ovewrite get_context_data to add formset as an additionnal parameter
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IssuesListUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            # if Save All issues button submitted
            if 'save_all' in self.request.POST.keys():
                formset = IssueFormset(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
                # sending formset to the template
                context['issues_formset'] = formset
                # save in the DB (saves only what has changed)
                #https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset
                # if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
                # re-update context with new formset, this is need to refresh table in case of deleting an object
                # without this, issue is deleted but still visible in the table 
                context['issues_formset'] = IssueFormset(instance=self.object)
        else:
            # sending formset to the template
            context['issues_formset'] = IssueFormset(instance=self.object)
        return context
```

**In template:**

```
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <!-- Below line is important to avoid django exception: 
    [django 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with] -->
        {{ issues_formset.management_form }}
        <input name="save_all" type="submit" value="Save All Issues"> 
<div class="">
        <table id="formset" class="form" border="1">
                {% for form in issues_formset.forms %}
                  {% if forloop.first %}
                  <thead><tr>
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tr></thead>
                  {% endif %}
                  <tr>
                  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <td>
                    {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                      {{ hidden }}
                      {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                      {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                      {{ field }}
                    </td>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </table>  

</div>
</form>
```

hope it will help someone, please let me know if you have any comments

Comment: If you want to update a table row without opening a new page you'll need AJAX (javascript) to send the request and catch the response to update the table row.

Comment: thanks. Don't I need to use formsets ?

Comment: You could wrap each table row into a <form> tag, but its not mandatory. You can just sent an ajax request with the updated data. You could consider looking at a frontend framework where this might be easier.